# Why are the following elements displaying on the bottom edge of the div?

Tags: html, css

HTML:

```
<div id="header">
        <img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150">
        <a href="1.html">blah</a>
        <a href="2.html">blah</a>
        <a href="3.html">blah</a>
</div>
```

The image is a placeholder for a logo.

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Tahoma, Arial;
}

#header img {
    margin-right: 130px;
}

#header a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: 60px;
    color: #000000;
}
```

Essentially, I want the labels "blah" to be at the vertical center of the image. I have already tried adding bottom and top padding and margins within the "#header a" selector, but it's not working. The labels continue aligning with the bottom edge of the picture.

Comment: You want the `a` tags to be over the image on the center?

Comment: Try adding a line-height:##px; to the a tags.

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but maybe you are looking for the verical-align property? Try setting `vertical-align:middle` on the `img`

Comment: I want the layout to be a horizontal strip like as follows:  image  blah blah blah          with the "blahs" at the vertical center of the image.

Comment: @ajf1000 you can check my answer, i think you need this..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this css, i think this can helpful for you, and see  [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/zsv0fp4a/)

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Century Gothic", Tahoma, Arial;
}

#header img {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 60px;
}

#header a {
  color: #000000;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 40px;
  padding: 9% 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put the image as a background for the div, you could set the background with the image.

```
  #header{
        background-image: url("https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=350%C3%97150&w=350&h=150");
        text-align:center;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this attributes to your css selector - `#header img`

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```

I have created a fiddle for you. Can you just check it. Hope this helps.

https://jsfiddle.net/uh4hs4ze/